# Angular directive parameter length limit

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs-directive

Is there a length limit for a parameter that is sent to a directive? Here is my code:

```
header = JSON.stringify(header);
columnObj = JSON.stringify(columnObj);
$compile('<div column-filter-sort header=' + header + ' columnobj=' +     columnObj + '></div>')(scope);
```

Directive:

```
a.directive('columnFilterSort', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var columnObj = JSON.parse(attrs.columnobj);
        var header = JSON.parse(attrs.header);
}
});
```

Var columnObj looks fine, but it fails at var header = JSON.parse(attrs.header);
Checking var header I see that it's not complete. The error I am getting is:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First change your compile to:

```
$compile('<column-filter-sort header="' + header + '" columnobj="' +     columnObj + '"></div>')(scope);
```

Second change directive to:

```
a.directive('columnFilterSort', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
            'header' : '=',
            'columnobj' : '='
         },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var columnObj = JSON.parse(scope.columnobj);
        var header = JSON.parse(scope.header);
}
});
```

That should do the trick.
For more details check this post
[how to pass a json as a string param to a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687822/how-to-pass-a-json-as-a-string-param-to-a-directive)

BTW, you can also pass the JSON to the global scope at the first JS section and consume it without using isolation scope in the directive.

Comment: The reason that is works because compile need to wrap the json with quotation mark. and the trick was to pass the json to isolation scope at the directive with double binding instead of using the attributes. @Toni thanks for the feedback

Comment: I am not sure but now it's not even getting into the directive.

Comment: And the error is Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/ueoe?p0=%7B
    at Error (native)

Comment: Please check my last edit on placing the column-filter-sort as element since restricting that in the directive

Comment: I have changed my compile to this $compile('<column-filter-sort header="' + header + '" columnobj="' + columnObj + '"></column-filter-sort>')(scope);

Comment: And still I am not getting into the directive. Console shows same parse error.

Comment: I only can get into the directive if I comment out isolated scope in there.

Comment: Where are you using the compile? Can you post that code?