# Custom message using standard validation message bubble in Angular JS

Tags: validation, angularjs

I want to create a custom validator. All the examples of doing this that I've seen involve showing an error message by switching on a span tag.

I would like to know how to use the standard error messaging tool tips to show a custom validation message from a custom validator.

Here's an example of the standard error message tool tips (press on the button!)....

```
<form>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" />
<button>SAVE</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IanIan123/Nnrrf/

I want to create validator that confirms two password entry boxes are the same if they're not, shows an appropriate message inside the tool tip.

Comment: you can use this solution for pretty close question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012239/password-check-directive-in-angularjs

Comment: btw, that basic message is a result of html5 validation, nothing to do with angular. if you simply want to change it, you could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message