# Angularjs+how to take a previous input field value in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form in which there are 2 date fields, from `date` and `todate`. I am writing a directive to compare this date field.

How to take the from date filed.I am invoking my custom directive on the `onBlur` of `toDate` and now need to take fromdate.The form design is as fillows.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
    <label>From date</label>
    <input type="text" id="eduFromDate" name="eduFromDate" class="form-control" 
           ng-model="education.fromDate" ui-date/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
    <label>To date</label>
    <input type="text" name="edutoDate" class="form-control" id="edutoDate" 
           ng-model="education.toDate" ui-date before-date/>
    <span class="error input-icon fui-alert" 
          ng-show="historyForm.edutoDate.$error.beforeDate"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bTFMzV70vjOzwhimVtQL?p=preview) will help.  Are you looking to calculate a date range?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom form validation directive to compare two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982751/custom-form-validation-directive-to-compare-two-fields)

Comment: @stewie your link helped me a lot in developing the directive.

Comment: @Stewie thank you for your link it helped me a lot.I am comparing 2 dates say start date and end date.In one of my form clone of these elements are taken.So how can I recognize each element differently.Below given is my html code and directive.

Answer (score 0):

My directive code is as follows.

```
directives.directive('beforeDate', [
    function() {

        var link = function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {

            var validate = function(viewValue) {
                var comparisonModel = $attrs.beforeDate;
                console.log(new Date(comparisonModel));
                if(!viewValue || !comparisonModel){
                    ctrl.$setValidity('beforeDate', true);
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity('beforeDate', new Date(viewValue) > new Date(comparisonModel) );
                return viewValue;
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(validate);

            $attrs.$observe('beforeDate', function(comparisonModel){
                console.log('comparisonModel '+comparisonModel)
                return validate(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });

        };

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link
        };

    }
]);
```

and in the form I have given like

```
<span ng-repeat="education in userEducation">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
      <label>From date</label>
      <input type="text" id="eduFromDate" name="eduFromDate" class="form-control" ng-model="education.fromDate" ui-date>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
      <label>To date</label>
      <div class="form-group has-success">
        <input type="text" name="edutoDate" class="form-control" id="edutoDate" ng-model="education.toDate" ui-date before-date="eduFromDate">
        <span class="error input-icon fui-alert" ng-show="historyForm.edutoDate.$error.beforeDate"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```