# Angular JS - How can I get the ngModelController by its model name?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

In my custom directive, I need to update the validity of another input. The directive is something like this :
`<customDirective="foo">`, in which the value foo is the name of another ngModel.

In my direcitve, I can get its model by :
`var foo = scope[attrs.foo];`.

But how can I get its ngModelController, to set its validity? Just like this :
`fooModelController.$setValidity('customDirective', true);`

EDIT :

In html, the input is defined as :

```
<input type="text" name="dateDebut" id="dateDebut" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.dateDebut" customDirective="dateFin" required>
<input type="text" name="dateFin" id="dateFin" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.dateFin" customDirective="dateDebut" required>
```

I get the dom node by `angular.element.find(document.querySelctor('#dateDebut'))`;

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You are most likely approaching something incorrectly. If you gave a broader context, we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @NewDev Hello, I have two inputs of dates, a start and an end. I would like to check whether the interval pass 1 week or not. If it is valid, both input should turn to valid.

Comment: $el.controller('ngModel') will give you the ngModelController of $el where $el is the reference of the dom node on which `ng-model` attribute is specified.

Comment: Probably the most elegant way would be to create a custom input directive that supports `ng-model`: `<date-range ng-model="dateRangeObj"></date-range>`, and use 2 individual inputs in its template. Another cheaper approach is to use a `ng-form` over the 2 inputs, which would be invalid if one of the inputs is invalid.

Comment: @NewDev Thanks for your suggestion, but the 2 suggestions both seems to be complex for me. Because I have other directives on these input.

Comment: @VinayK I get a undefined exception, when calling  
$el.controller('ngModel')

Comment: $el should be a jqlite/jquery reference. Can you show the code where `ng-model=foo` is defined?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982751/custom-form-validation-directive-to-compare-two-fields

Comment: @Dreamwalker It's not definitely the same scenario. In that question, it controle just one input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.element(document.querySelctor('#dateDebut')).controller('ngModel')` -- this will give the `ngModelController` defined on `#dateDebut` element.

Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qXyxEb2QHyhuRUttNMXn?p=preview