# AngularJS can't get my matching (two fields) directive to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

The following directive is based on the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982751/custom-form-validation-directive-to-compare-two-fields), I'm using Angular 1.2.27. My problem is that for whatever reason it won't validate to true because it never makes it further than `if (!viewValue || !comparisonModel) {` because `viewValue` is always undefined.

Given the fact the other question is basically the same just with comparing integers I guess it's something pretty stupid that I'm missing or doing wrong here.

So, why is `viewValue` undefined and how do I get it to work as expected? [Plunker is here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gT8bZglNswURbt0cX1Es)

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = {
    password: '',
    password2: ''
  };

});

app.directive('waMatch', [
    function () {
        var link = function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {

            var validate = function (viewValue) {
                var comparisonModel = $attrs.waMatch;

                if (!viewValue || !comparisonModel) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('waMatch', true);
                }

                ctrl.$setValidity('waMatch', (viewValue === comparisonModel));
                return viewValue;
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(validate);

            $attrs.$observe('waMatch', function (comparisonModel) {
                return validate(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });

        };

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link
        };
    }
]);
```

HTML:

```
  Password: <input name="password" type="password" required ng-model="fields.password" />
  <span class="error" ng-show="form.password.$error.required && !form.password.$pristine">
    Required.
  </span>

  <br />

  Password2: <input name="password2" type="password" required ng-model="fields.password2" wa-match="{{password}}"/>
  <span class="error" ng-show="form.password2.$error.waMatch">
    Passwords must match.
  </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a small typo ...

wa-match="{{password}}"

Should be:

wa-match="{{fields.password}}"

So the html should be:

```
Password2: <input name="password2" type="password" required ng-model="fields.password2" wa-match="{{fields.password}}"/>
```

Comment: Ah crap...! Something stupid like I thought... Thank you! No more late night coding for me.