# Angularjs 1.30 password verify. Validate confirm password matches

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passwords, directive

Total noob here. I'm using Angularjs 1.30 and trying to get confirm password to work. I want it such that if the "password" and "confirm_password" input fields match and validate, if I then modify either of the two fields, the form will no longer be valid.

I think [Dominic Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419935/dominic-watson) gave an answer in [password-check directive in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012239/password-check-directive-in-angularjs), but pasting his module it into my .js and including it in my `var app = angular.module('myapp', ['validators'])` doesn't seem to work because...well, I don't know how to attach/use modules... (so if you can explain how I can use the modules like the one he posted into my own project, that would be great too!)

I've tried most everything I could find, and as Dominic pointed out, the problem seems to be that in Angular 1.30, "invalid inputs don't write to ngModel"

Answer (score 1):

Does app lives in my.js? If you have many js files, you have to build them using some build tool, like gulp.
I can't say why it does't work for you without seeing your code. I think you should publish it and show us.
You can try my [solution](http://demibyte.com/2015/05/19/angularjs-password-match/). It does pretty much the same.