# How to do reverse password validation in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do password validation in AngularJs.

**HTML**

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword1"   name="Password" class="form-control" data-ng-model="passwordd"  ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9_+@&$#!^%*-]{6,10}$/"  placeholder="Password" required />
<span ng-show="myForm.Password.$error.pattern"><span style="color:red">Must contain minimum 6 characters</span></span>

<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" ng-change="doPwdMatch()" name="password" data-ng-model="password2"  placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
<span ng-show="pwdDonotMatch"> <span style="color:red">Passwords don't match.</span> </span>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.doPwdMatch=function(){

            if(($scope.password2!=="" || $scope.password2==undefined ) && $scope.passwordd !== $scope.password2){
                    $scope.pwdDonotMatch = true;
            }else
                    $scope.pwdDonotMatch = false;
            }
```

It showing error if the confirm password does not match with password. But it is not validating if I clear the password field and input some other value. To be specific, reverse checking is not happening.

Comment: You might want to put the same `ng-change` on password1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14012512/5246

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `ng-change="doPwdMatch()"` in your password tag to do this,

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword1"   name="Password" class="form-control" data-ng-model="passwordd" ng-change="doPwdMatch()"  ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9_+@&$#!^%*-]{6,10}$/"  placeholder="Password" required />
<span ng-show="myForm.Password.$error.pattern"><span style="color:red">Must contain minimum 6 characters</span></span>

<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" ng-change="doPwdMatch()" name="password" data-ng-model="password2"  placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
<span ng-show="pwdDonotMatch"> <span style="color:red">Passwords don't match.</span> </span>
```

**Edit**

You can add this logic inside your function `pwdDonotMatch()`. That is you can check whether the model for `password2` has any value or not.

```
$scope.doPwdMatch = function () {
    if ($scope.password2 == "" || $scope.passwordd == "") {
        // If any one field is null, then do not display error message
        $scope.pwdDonotMatch = true;
    }
    else if (($scope.password2 !== "" || $scope.password2 == undefined) && $scope.passwordd !== $scope.password2) {
        $scope.pwdDonotMatch = true;
    } else
        $scope.pwdDonotMatch = false;
}
```

Comment: Problem with adding ng-change="doPwdMatch()" in  password tag is, when I type in password field it will validate before entering something in the confirm password field. It should wait for something to be entered in the confirm password field

Comment: @Yogesh, Sorry, please have a  look now.

Comment: The problem is if the confirm password field is empty, the error message should not be shown. I t should show only if the passwords dont match

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to call a `ng-change`?

With `ng-model`, your scope is always the current input value, so you can just do it via an `ng-if="password1 !== password2"`

So for example:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="PasswordCtrl">

    <input type="password" id="inputPassword1"   name="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required />

    <span ng-show="myForm.Password.$error.pattern"><span style="color:red">Must contain minimum 6 characters</span></span>

    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control"name="password" ng-model="reenter_password"  placeholder="Confirm Password" required />

    <span ng-if="password !== reenter_password"> 
        <span style="color:red">Passwords don't match.</span> 
    </span>
</div>
```

And your Controller is simply this:

```
function PasswordCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.reenter_password = "";
}
```

See this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/) I've created out of your code.