# How to check for confirm password in the signup page using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write code for checking confirm password using angularjs.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My signUp.html:

```
<html ng-app="Sample">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom.css" />
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-messages.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="wrapper1" align="center" ng-controller="RegistrationController as registration" >
        <div>
            <img id="logoDiv" src="../images/favicon.png">
        </div>
        <div id="loginDiv">
            <h2>Sign up</h2>

            <form>
                <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email" /><br> <br>
                <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" placeholder="Password" /><br><br> 
                 <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" placeholder="Verify Password" /><br><br> 
               <a href="#/signUp"> <button class="resizedBtn" value="SIGN UP">SignUp
                </button></a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [password-check directive in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012239/password-check-directive-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same question as you, and found a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21992003/5523774). I used the 'nxEqual' directive and my form inputs look like this:

```
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password"
           ng-required="true"
           ng-minlength="8">

<input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" ng-model="user.passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password"
           ng-required="true"
           ng-minlength="8"
           nx-equal="user.password">
```

To display a message like "Passwords do not match", i used this line ("signUpForm" is the name of myform.):

```
<div ng-show="signUpForm.passwordConfirm.$error.nxEqual"> Passwords do not match.</div >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a ng-model to both password fields , and below the text fields use an ng-show with condition that if both password match then show success message

```
    <form>
                <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email" /><br> <br>
                <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" /><br><br> 
                 <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" ng-model="verify-password" placeholder="Verify Password" /><br><br> 
<div ng-show="password === verify-password" > password matched </div>
               <a href="#/signUp"> <button class="resizedBtn" value="SIGN UP">SignUp
                </button></a>
            </form>
```

similarly you can use ng-hide to show error message

Answer (score 0):

Use like this by using custom directive "verifyPassword" & use **form_name.password2.$error.noMatch** property in ng-show, to display the error:

```
 <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password"/>   // password html
 <input verifyPassword type="text"  name="password2" class="resizedTextbox" placeholder="Verify Password"/>  //confirm password html
```

And use this directive,

```
Buyer.directive('verifyPassword', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {

            var noMatch = viewValue != scope.regForm.password.$viewValue

            ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch)
           return (noMatch)?noMatch:viewValue;

        })
    }
}
```

});