# Confirm password in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

https://embed.plnkr.co/oCd2WrzJjFtvgsGdHrdV3b/

Hello , I created Login page and Register page. But I need to add an additional functionality of confirm password. I am pretty confused in handling this with my controllers.

can anyone help me in validation part.

When I give Ng-match or directives , it is not compatible with my existing controller. Either it states Registration successful in case of wrong password or else my view is just empty in browser.

Comment: this question has been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012239/password-check-directive-in-angularjs

Comment: When I give Ng-match or directives , it is not compatible with my existing controller. Either it states Registration successful in case of wrong password or else my view is just empty in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plnkr.co/edit/LRXKpql1AxmGNcTWifGS?p=preview

I solved the issue you faced with confirmPassword. I'm just 
saying where you made the mistake
1)password name in ng-modal and name in "required data-password-verify" at confirm password should match when you compare two passwords.
2)Please have a look at console first,then you understand where you did a mistake.Console clearly saying two issues i.e app is not defined at passwordVerify.js and User service not defined.
3)I changed passwordVerfiy directive to register controller and I commented userservice wherever i find.Because I have not seen anywhere you are using Userservice class.Both the files(user.service and user.service,localstorage) are empty

I would be more happy if my code resolve your problem.
Thank you

Comment: Yes thank you. I will follow up using console to check out my errors.

Comment: Ashok Reddy.. I have one more doubt. http://plnkr.co/edit/zl4prZVBIRzp1CzpbyE3?p=preview  I have local storage to store my datas locally , what if I want to move datas to server side using JSOn. Namely My JSon is .REGISTER CANDIDATE 
------------------------
URL : http://localhost:8080/Registration?request={JSONREQUEST}
-----

Comment: REQUEST:
--------

{"json":  
       {"request":
                 {"servicetype":"21",
                  "functiontype":"1001",

                     "data":{
                            "email":"abc@gmail.com",
                            "password":"12345",
                            "retypepassword":"12345"
                           }
                 }
        }
}

RESPONSE :
----------

{

    "json":{
        "response":{
            "servicetype":"21",
            "functiontype":"1001",
            "statuscode":"0",
            "statusmessage":"Success"
        }
    }

}

Comment: I didn't get you exactly.But as far as I understand you need to send data to server as JSON. for this use $http.post('api/register', JSON.stringify(formData)). in your user service. It will stringify you data as JSON automatically

Comment: yes You are correct , I need to send datas from registration page to server . So dont I have any use with  URL : localhost:8080/Registration?request={JSONREQUEST}  .

Comment: You can send data in url by using $stateparams,But it's not secure.To the best of my knowledge better to go with JSON data than $stateparams.

Answer (score 2):

Use following ng-match directive

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-match

Comment: When I give Ng-match or directives , it is not compatible with my existing controller. Either it states Registration successful in case of wrong password or else my view is just empty in browser.