# Problems with password matching with Angular Auto Validate

Tags: angularjs

Trying to integrate [**Angular Auto Validate's**](http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/) password matching/confirmation example into a form. I'm not getting any errors but the password matching code is not kicking in. What's the simplest way to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a plunkr of my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZRAJGZdQ3IeamcKNdkH?p=preview)

Here's the password matching code I'm trying to integrate:

```
function ConfirmPasswordValidatorDirective(defaultErrorMessageResolver) {
  defaultErrorMessageResolver.getErrorMessages().then(function (errorMessages) {
      errorMessages['confirmPassword'] = 'Please ensure the passwords match.';
    });

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        scope : {
            confirmPassword : '=confirmPassword'
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.confirmPassword = function(modelValue) {
                return modelValue === scope.confirmPassword;
            };

            scope.$watch('confirmPassword', function() {
                ngModel.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
}

ConfirmPasswordValidatorDirective.$inject = [
  'defaultErrorMessageResolver'
];
```

[Here's a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/W1NFc8tRueMEzJrpOUeZ?p=preview) of angular-auto-validate's password matching code working.

Comment: There are a lot of posts / ready directives to do this, look this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012239/password-check-directive-in-angularjs

Comment: Thank you, I don't feel that addresses the specific issues in the above post using Angular Auto Validate.

Comment: True, I didn't notice you're using a module since you didn't put it specifically.

Comment: :) Thanks. We were both editing that info at the same time.

Comment: I find your error, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first you forgot to call the *directive* in your view, so you should include it in your *confirmPassword* `<input>`:

```
confirm-password="formModel.password"
```

Also you haven't declared the directive in your **JS** file:

```
app.directive('confirmPassword', ConfirmPasswordValidatorDirective);
```

Look: <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/snVd7YpepggNXV32HfuY?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you fantastic. 

Ah " see, `scope : {
                confirmPassword : '=confirmPassword'
            },` was not reflected in the confirmPassword `<input>`

Just one question so I can understand: why did you remove `class="control-label"` on the password labels?

Comment: Hmm, maybe, I copied the fields of their plnkr :), but you can just do these modifications above on **your** plnkr and it will works.